# Caching file in memory on Express (and sending it to the browser properly)

Tags: node.js, http, express, caching

We have a cache of some of the .js files (static assets) on an Express server. We need to send the right headers.

If we do `res.send(cache[filepath])`, then it will send a response to the browser, but the browser doesn't know it's a file (tmk).

On the other hand, `res.sendFile(filepath)`, takes a filepath, not a string in memory.

So what is the best way to send the file from the cache?
Is it a simple case of:

```
res.write('\n\n' + cache[filepath] + '\n'); 
res.end();
```

?

here is the code I am working on:
https://github.com/ORESoftware/express.fs.cache

here is a relevant conversation on Github:
https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/issues/107

Comment: Isn't a filepath a string?

Comment: `filepath` is a string always, and `cache[filepath]`, if it exists, is a string in memory representing the file's contents

Comment: What do you mean by "but the browser doesn't know it's a file".  Data is data.  It doesn't matter whether the data originated from a file on your disk or from a string in memory.  When it gets sent to the client, it's just data.

Comment: nah dogg, if it gets sent with `content-type` as `plain/text` or something, it gets displayed in the browser instead of put in the file cache in the browser. headers matter. or maybe I am confused lol.

Comment: I would write a cache handler, collecting stuff, included this file, the first time you open it. Then you can just retrieve the file from there.

Comment: You can control the content-type yourself by just setting that header with `res.header()` before you send the data. If you don't set the content-type, Express will guess which may not always be right.

Comment: please critique the code as is: https://github.com/ORESoftware/express.fs.cache